# Symfony - How to set URL prefix when using Proxy

Tags: php, apache, symfony

im trying to set a global prefix for the symfony application to run the application behind a reverse proxy.

The Proxy URL is  http://proxy.example.de/ski

The locaton /ski is causing trouble.

I'm using Symfony 4, the configuration mentioned in the documentation did not work :

```
parameters:
    router.request_context.host: www.fakedomain.com
    router.request_context.scheme: http
    router.request_context.base_url: fakedirectory
```

The app is running on an apache , the proxy is an apache too.
I tried setting a route_prefix in the annotation.yaml, that does not solve the asset problem and was causing other problems.

Thanks in advance.

Edit:
Example Controller Route

```
class DashboardController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="dashboard")
     *
     * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function index(EntityManagerInterface $em)
```

Comment: what's your routing like?

Comment: What do you mean ? The routes are made by annotation inside the controller.

Comment: then, can we see the controller? :)

Comment: Of course, but i doubt that there is the problem. As i said, i could set a global prefix in the annotations.yaml and that would fix the routing problem. But then i still run into problems with my assets. I added a route into my post.

Comment: `/ski` isn't a route though? what's the actual error? `404`?

Comment: /ski is the location on the proxy. Symfony thinks its a parameter and http://proxy.example.de is the base path. But the base_url/path of the application would be http://proxy.example.de/ski.

Comment: is it a an app within an app? or will enduser always go to `proxy.example.de/ski`?

Comment: It is a single Application. We just use a reverse proxy to host multiple applications (symfony, springboot , python) under the same URL like "http://portal.example.de". Then the locations are  /application1 , /application2 , /ski.
So for my symfony application the context root is always proxy.example.de/ski

Comment: then why not set document root to be `/ski`? If the site will always run through `/ski/*` then just set the base url as such?

Comment: What do you mean where to set it ? On the Proxy, Host or Application ? If that is a working solution i would love to do that :-)

Comment: Just as the application, so you're dashboard route would be `/ski` - then anything after can use `{ski}/*` as url and set defaults for ski to `/ski`

Comment: I already tried that. That is like setting a prefix with /ski for all routes. I still have a problem with my assets then.

Comment: but if documentroot is set then it goes from /public no?

Comment: I think i missunderstood you. Can you please explain what you meant by setting the documentroot to ski ?

Comment: So in your vhost file / nginx conf file - you'd set the document root to be `example.com/ski` then you can just use that - alternatively you could use routing to set everything to `/ski` then your public folder isn't an issue, because the url will still read `/public/*` as the public assest folder

Comment: Im unable to get the document root solution working. If i set anything else then the url to the public folder ( /var/www/sf4/public ) it doesnt find anything. Any idea what im doing wrong ?

Comment: Any solution? I have the same problem. symfony-app1 listens on `x.x.x.x:7071/` and `symfony-app2` listens on `x.x.x.x:7072/` - I use caddyserver to route `example.com:443/app1` to one server and `example.com:443/app2` to the other. With the `without` directive on caddy, I can reach the proper page in symfony. For example the `/app1` gets converted to `/` and `app1/someThing` gets requested as `/someThing`. But if application 1 responds with a link to `/someThing` I still don't get it converted back to `/app1/someThing` after responded by the reverse proxy.